# How to calculate events per hour by route and daterange

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How can I calculate stops per hour by route and date
model:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    route = models.Integer(...
    on_route_time = models.TimeField(...
    dropoff_stops = models.Integer(...
    pickup_stops = models.Integer(...
    date = models.DateTime(...
```

My query:

`def stops_per_hour(date): 
    query_set = MyModel.objects.filter(date=date).values(
        'route', 'dropoff_stops','pickup_stops','on_route_time').annotate(
            total=(Sum('actual_stops') + Sum('pickup_stops'))).order_by('route')`

which gives me:

```
<<QuerySet [{'route': 226, 'dropoff_stops': 84, 'pickup_stops': 0, 'on_route_time': datetime.time(5, 23), 'total': 84},{'route': 242, 'dropoff_stops': 33, 'pickup_stops': 0, 'on_route_time': datetime.time(3, 24), 'total': 33}]>>
```

I'm stuggling with how calculating stops/hour for each route and passing this to the view (e.g. route 226 stops/hour = 15.18. Suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've finally solved it. Would be interested in suggestions for improvement.

```
new_set = []
for i in query_set:
    time = i.get('on_route_time')
    stops = i.get('dropoff_stops') + i.get('pickup_stops)
    route = i.get('route')

    try:
        time.hour * 60 + time.minute > 0
        sph = round(stops / (time.hour * 60 + time.minute) * 60, 1)
        dict = {'route':route, 'sph', sph}
        new_set.append(dict)
    except:
        sph = 0
        new_set.append(dict)
return new_set
```

Try handles both type and divide by zero issues.